# How can i search second or third word on PeoplePicker?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, people-picker, react

I have a peoplePicker on my sharePoint project, *react,
and I am using this for search users or groups. I can find all.. but there is an another problem.

It's okay if I write the words in order but if I start searching from the second or third word, I can't get any results. Is there any way to solve this? or a setting? thanks

this is ok:

[image]

but this is not ok:

[image]

```
<PeoplePicker
elementClassName="documentCenterPP"
peoplePickerElementId="authGroupPeoplePicker"
placeholder={"test"}
allowMultipleValues={true}
principalAccountType="TestGroup,SPGroup"
maximumEntitySuggestions={50}
searchPrincipalSource={15}
resolvePrincipalSource={15}
enabled={!loading}
selectedUsers={selectedAuthGroup}
onUserResolved={(event: IPeoplePicker[]) =>
  handleSetPeoplePickerAuthGroup(event)
}
```